# Send SMS using Sikuli

Tags: sms, sikuli

According to my understanding, Sikuli is basically used for matching images that are present on the screen and working on it using Python, Jython.

I want to send an SMS using Sikuli using APIs. I know that there are some websites that allows to send SMSses. But I don't want to go and login into these websites using Sikuli (in case of automated programs). I only want to use an API that directly takes the mobile no., message and sends it to the receiver with-in the script. Some APIs are there which are used with Python to send SMS. But none of them is useful in Sikuli.

Can you please help me and tell of any method how I can implement this using Sikuli. I would be grateful.

Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use https://www.twilio.com/. You don't need to log in there. You can send/receive sms using their API. There are a lot of examples.
It is much easier then use Sikuli.